# Creating a new column in a Pandas DF that groups by age category

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to coding so I apologize for asking what could be a dumb and easy question. I have searched the web and read documents but I could not find an answer and after 4 hours I am hoping for guidance.

I have a Pandas DataFrame named **"data"**. **"data"** has a column for age with a ton of different ages. I would like to isolate certain age groups for different types of analysis. Like how many hours young adults work out (in an `snsplot`).

In my head, the best way to tackle this would have a column added in "data" that has the age_group. With the age group being assigned some logic (like in the picture attached)

I could be wrong, like I said I am only a few months into just learning python. Thanks for any help given. I plan on doing this on a few more columns once I know how.

I tried to create variables based on the age groups I was looking for

```py
teenage = data[data['age']<=19]
yadult = data[data['age'].between(20,24)]
adult = data[data['age'].between(25,39)]
older_adult = data[data['age']>39]
```

That did not work when I tried to use the variable in a `snsplot`.

So I then tried this:

```py
data['yadult'] = data[data['age'].between(20,24)]
```

but got an error:
**"ValueError: The wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1**

The end goal here is to have the "data" DataFrame with a brand new column with the age group. Like below.

| Product | Age | Gender | Education | .... | age_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TM195 | 18 | Male | 14 | ...... | teenager |
| TM195 | 27 | Male | 16 | ...... | adult |

.csv data layout :
[image]

The buckets I am trying to create:
[image]

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and your code as clear text. Thanks

Comment: I added more infor. I hope that helps. I am not 100% sure what I needed to provide.

Comment: please paste in the values and code, not the images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following code, you can assign a new column `age_group` according to `age`:

```
data.loc[data['age']<=19, 'age_group'] = 'teenage'
data.loc[data['age'].between(20,24), 'age_group'] = 'yadult'
data.loc[data['age'].between(25,39), 'age_group'] = 'adult'
data.loc[data['age']>39, 'age_group'] = 'older_adult'
```

Comment: Thank you so very much this worked! I might be able to finish this project now. Thank you x 3000

Comment: Please accept and upvote this answer if it is helpful, thanks! @dumbnhumble